無為 (wu wei) "effortless action": how to translate to Latin?
The Taoist concept of "wu wei" (無為) would have seemed pretty obvious to an ancient stoic. According to Wikipedia, it is "[...] an ancient Chinese concept which has a polymorphic meaning that expresses inexertion, inaction, or effortless action."
I am having trouble finding such a polymorphic translation into Latin. Inertia? Non-actio? They don't seem to capture it. The stress shouldn't be on literal inaction, but on the skilful effortlessness of accomplishments, on the natural flow of action.
Would you know of a better Latin translation of "wu wei"? Maybe a similar concept from stoic writings?
